# How do I get product category information using collections in Magento

Tags: collections, magento

I am trying to output all the products from our Magento shop - the following code works, however I also need to grab the category id & the parent category name too. Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

```php
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$productCollection = $product->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');


foreach ( $productCollection as $_product ) {
    echo $_product->getName().'<br/>';        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since products can be assigned to multiple categories, I think your concept may be a bit off unless you are loading a collection for each category. What do you anticipate seeing if there are multiple categories for a given product?

Regardless, from within a category page, you can use the following:

```
$currentCat = $_product->getCategory();
```

To get all categories to which this product belongs:

```
$categories = $_product->getCategoryCollection();
foreach($categories as $_category) {
    // do something
}
```

Hope that helps. Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Thanks for that Joe! Magento is one beast that i'm not a big fan of at the minute! :-)

Answer (score 8):

In some instances $_product->getCategory() can return empty and cause an error.

A better solution is to fetch categories by ID:

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    echo $category->getName();
    echo $category->getUrlPath();
 }
```