# Magento: Query Database for products with no assigned categories

Tags: magento

I'm really new to Magento and I'm looking to find a way to get a list of all the products in the catalog which are not assigned to any categories. Can anyone offer any help as to how this can be achieved?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Select entity_id from catalog_product_entity where entity_id not in (select distinct product_id from catalog_category_product);`

This will give you all product entity id not belonging to any category.

Answer (score 0):

You can get product collection by using following code :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$productCollection = $product->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*');


foreach ( $productCollection as $_product ) {
    echo $_product->getName().'<br/>';        
}
```

But for your requirement you can get idea from following links,may be its help you.
[How do I get product category information using collections in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454561/how-do-i-get-product-category-information-using-collections-in-magento)